# Openerp create() method returning new recordset ID but not updating database

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I am developing a webservice in OpenERP 7 that create a new partner on the res_partner table with a POST method. My problem is that the `create()` method return me the new object ID, but the database is not updated.

Here is my code:

```
@openerpweb.httprequest
def add_partner(self, req, db, user, password, name, type, street, city, zip, phone, email, function):
    uid = req.session.authenticate(db, user, password)
    osv_pool = pooler.get_pool(db)
    cr = pooler.get_db(db).cursor()

    partner_pool = osv_pool.get('res.partner')
    partner_dict = {
        'name': name,
        'type': type,
        'street': street,
        'city': city,
        'zip': zip,
        'phone': phone,
        'email': email,
        'function': function
    }

    result = partner_pool.create(cr, uid, partner_dict)
    cr.close()
    return str(result)
```

The method doesn't give me any error, and the request return a 200 code, with the new ID. I can't find why the database is not being updated in this create method

Comment: it returns a browse_record(res.partner, 9840)

Comment: The last entry id on the database is 9832, and everytime I try to add a new partner the ID is incremented, but no entry is added to the databse

Comment: As I understood, record was created and you got ID of new record. But  new record is not exists in table. Is it right?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar yes, it is.

Comment: strangely. I worked with this object and I had no problems with this method. Try to use next way: `partner_pool.sudo().create(cr, uid, partner_dict)`. Maybe this help you.

Comment: Using sudo() gives me ''res.partner' object has no attribute 'sudo''

Comment: I used cr.close() before returnig, and now I can make other POST requests without problem, but it still doesn't save to database

Comment: Here example which works: `for lead in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context): lead.env['res.partner'].sudo().create({ 'name': lead.name, ...})`. Lead - `crm.lead`

Comment: I did not used `@openerpweb.httprequest` before. Maybe there can be any nuance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem. I needed to commit the changes on the cursor object, so I used `cr.commit()` and succesfully added the entry on the database.

Comment: Thanks. Good luck ;)